# Why are Views important in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I'm learning postgresql and just going through the docs. I'm at the section where they are talking about Views. I understand views as they are essentially query blocks (similar to functions in python) which I can call. I also understand when and why I would use them.

My confusion is with this sentence [in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-views.html):

> Views allow you to encapsulate the details of the structure of your tables, which might change as your application evolves, behind consistent interfaces

I'm not sure what that means. When I read that it encapsulates the details I thought it meant views are good for security purposes to hide queries over request.body.

Why are views good for when my application evolves behind consistent interfaces?

Comment: That means than views are based on a subset of fields of one or many tables. If some of these tables evolve (change, for example with new columns) the view keep in the same state, so there is no need to change contract interfaces after those changes on the source tables.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying Jamie and thanks for the response. Just a little confused by - "no need to change contract interfaces after those changes on the source tables." - Not sure exactly what that means, I'm a noob.

Comment: View may be used as an interface: you come with agreement about the structure you need and you now do not need to worry about the storage model.

Comment: @jarjarbinks99 Jamie's statement means that you may change involved underlying tables in any way, and the only thing to keep in mind is the contract that should be fulfilled.

Comment: @astentx thank you sir that makes more sense now

Comment: By the way, this kind of question might be better asked in the sister site, [*Database Administrators Stack Exchange*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Perhaps one of the Comment authors cares to write up an Answer so this page can be marked as resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views can act as an abstraction layer. Imagine this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE userdata (
   userid bigint PRIMARY KEY,
   username text UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   favorite_color text NOT NULL
);

CREATE VIEW v_userdata AS
SELECT userid, username, favorite_color
FROM userdata;
```

The application always accesses the data through the view.

Now at some point you realize that this data model should be improved and normalized. So you change it to

```
CREATE TABLE color (
   colorid bigint PRIMARY KEY,
   name text UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE userdata (
   userid bigint PRIMARY KEY,
   username text UNIQUE NOT NULL,
   favorite_color bigint REFERENCES color NOT NULL
);

CREATE VIEW v_userdata AS
SELECT ud.userid, ud.username,
       c.name AS favorite_color
FROM userdata AS ud
   JOIN color AS c ON ud.favorite_color = c.colorid;
```

Then you need not change anything in the application, even though the table layout has changed.